# How would I make this glow?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm making a lightsaber in Cycles Render.
I'm pretty new to blender and only started yesterday.
I've been watching YouTube Videos but usually I can't access something they have and usually messes it up.
I'm fine doing compositing and Nodes I just need to know how to make this glow,
Current (v)
[image: Picture]
Nodes
[image: Picture2]
Current Compositing Nodes
[image: Picture3]

Again I just need this to glow but i keep on messing up! Please help, thank you

Comment: Do you mean a halo effect like the one discussed here? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46660/creating-a-halo-effect-for-a-material-in-cycles

Comment: Could you post a picture of what you're trying to achieve? Thank you! :)

Comment: Use fog glow glare node in compositor.  Simple emission shader as volume for material would be enough I think.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34002/glow-effect-invisible-on-transparent-background and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93752/lightsaber-effect-in-cycles-without-compositing